# How can I enabled urls like site.mydomain.com?

Tags: php, symfony, url, subdomain

I need to create dynamically subdomains for my URL.

I have a domain like mydomain.com working and I like after a user is enrolled in my web he can see their profile using the username as variable before the domain.

So I can have the following URL:

```
username.mydomain.com
anotheruser.mydomain.com
 usernameA.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Relevant docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

routing.yml:

```
homepage:
    path:     /
    host:     "{username}.example.com"
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:user
```

Controller

```
class MainController extends Controller {
    public function userAction($username) {

    } 
}
```

EDIT:

For Symfony 2.2 and above

Comment: Hi, that looks great! But I get this error: "0 Yaml routing loader does not support given key: "path". Expected one of the (type, resource, prefix, pattern, options, defaults, requirements).".
Can you help me to understand the reason?

Comment: To begin with - which symfony version? Oh, and try `prefix` instead of `path`.

Comment: Hi, this is my symfony version: 2.1.6
when I change the path for prefix, I get that the following key is not supported: "host"

The change is in the routing.yml in app/config folder, right?

Comment: You will have to update symfony. It appears `host` support in symfony appeared in 2.2 - https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/2.1/Route.php (see branches for other versions).